# Calling functions outside of the scope

Tags: jquery, scope

I am using `.load()` to load things into different elements on a page, say `#profileDisplay`, so when using e.g. a click function I do the following to bring it into the scope:

```
$('#profileDisplay').on("click", ".more", function() {
    ...
});
```

How can I bring a function which accesses a plug-in to do the same? e.g.

```
$('.glyphicon').not('.folderIcon').tooltipster({
     ...
});
```

I am trying the following but not working:

```
$('#profileDisplay.glyphicon').not('.folderIcon').tooltipster({
    ...
});
```

**SUMMARY** I load `thisFile.php` into element `#profileDisplay`

```
$("#profileDisplay").load('/ajax/actions/thisFile.php');
```

If I include

```
$('.glyphicon').not('.folderIcon').tooltipster({
     ...
});
```

WITHIN `thisFile.php` it works ok, but I use it in lots of pages so I want to include it say in the footer and from there it does not work

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to do.. can you add some html and say what elements do you want to access?

Comment: @Nelson Added summary, hopefully clearer now

Comment: Really your title doesn't seem to fit your question. Are you looking to delegate tooltipster plugin or what? If ya and if tooltipster plugin doesn't implement any kind of delegation, you have to reinitialisate tooltipster plugin on new added element using the `.load()` method success callback

Comment: It's not clear what you want to access or do. From what I can tell  `.on("click", ".more", function() { ...` written this way, is the former `live` method, which will attach the handler to all existing and future elements which matches the selector. Since you're using `load` is more likely that this is the case: the handler is not attached to the event of the newly added elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute code when your `.load()` ajax call has finished, you have two ways, attached to the [complete callback](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function) of `.load()` like this:

```
$("#profileDisplay").load('/ajax/actions/thisFile.php', function() {
   $('.glyphicon').not('.folderIcon').tooltipster({
        ...
   })
});
```

Or attach to the [ajaxComplete event](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) on the Document object, this will fire when any ajax call in your page is executed:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete( function() {
   $('.glyphicon').not('.folderIcon').tooltipster({
        ...
   })
});
```

Comment: ajaxComplete is new to me but does exactly what I need, brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect any plugin to work on an element that's not present on the page due to the fact you're loading it later, by the click event (if I understood correctly). That's why the function works when it's in thisFile.php.

What you should do is to call `$('.glyphicon').not('.folderIcon').tooltipster({...` in the callback of the load function. That way it will be called when your content is loaded and thus it will be present on the page and work just fine.

Not sure if your plugin has something like the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method which listens for DOM changes and works even with elements that appear after the call, but you might want to check that out as well.